# whats the difference between making the head and n in the code

Tags: c, list, struct

In this code a head object is made right in front of the structure definition,
but the n is made in int main.

Can we just declare both the way head was declared? I think I'm just not understanding how `struct node *n` is different from the way head was declared, because they are both objects right?

```
  struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    }*head;
    .
    .
    .
    int  main()
    {
        int i,num;
        struct node *n;
        head = NULL;
        ...
```

Comment: "*they are both objects right?*" - `head` and `n` both designate "objects" in the C standard's sense of the term, but so also do `i` and `num` designate objects in that sense.  I think you may mean "objects" in a more OO sense that equates to "structures", but here you must be careful: it is `*head` and `*n` that designate structures; `head` and `n` designate not structures but *pointers*, which are separate, independent objects (C sense) in their own right.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are mixing the declaration of `struct node` and the declaration of the variable `head`, which is correct C but TBH not very readable.

Write your code rather like that:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};                   // declaration of struct node

.
.
struct node *head;   //declaration of a variable head of type "pointer to struct node"
.
.
.
int  main()
{
    int i,num;
    struct node *n;   //declaration of a local variable n of type "pointer to struct node"
    head = NULL;
    ...
```

It's equivalent to your code, but more readable.

Answer (score 0):

"head" is a global pointer where as "n" is local pointer to node structure.

Also note that neither "head" nor "n" are objects. They are pointer to objects of node structure. You need to allocate memory for them.